# Momentum when someone falls to the ground (related to momentum, gravity, lever)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, momentum

According to Newton's laws, free fall is subjected to the pull of gravity at acceleration of 9.8 m/s per second (something like this). But I don't think the principle of "free fall" is applicable to calculate momentum when someone falls to the ground. It has a "fulcrum" in this process. (It is a second/third class lever). So, how can I calculate the velocity and acceleration of falling when the gravitational pull is "affected" by this lever system?

Comment: why are you thinking in terms of the fulcrum model..are the existing theries of gravity not satisfactory??

Comment: No, I think that "a person falling down" is not a free fall, and the acceleration and velocity might not be 9.8 m/s, because it is not same as a free fall (that is no any part touching the ground). So, I think the acceleration and velocity is effected by this lever system (*I think, maybe) Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Acceleration is given by the total, or net force acting an object.  This is just a clearer statement of your intuition: the ground imparts a force on the person as they're falling that reduces their acceleration downward by gravity.

If you were to put a scale under someone as they fell, you could read the force over time that the ground exerts on their feet.

Answer (score 1):

Free fall is simply the absence of weight under the influence of a gravitational field. What we perceive as weight on earth is simply the reaction force that the ground applies on our bodies.

When we fall on the ground, some weight is still perceived by us in the form of support provided our legs while falling. So, yes we are not in total free fall while falling on the ground. If, however none of the body parts of a person are being supported by the ground, we can indeed consider the person to be in free fall as long as he's accelerating at 9.8 m/s^2.